# Get Customer information inside Admin Panel

Tags: customer, adminhtml, session

I created a custom tab in the Admin Panel under
Customers -> Manage Customers -> My Custom Tab
At this point how can I get information about the customer I'm looking at, not the Admin User logged in.

The only tricky way I see is using getUrl and parsing through the url since the ID is in there but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current customer whose details are editing by following code.

```
$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
```

Customer instance is already stored in registry so that you can access it anywhere you need.

Hope that helps you.